# I'm getting a name error. "instance_dict is not defined"

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement tabu search algorithm, but I keep getting the following error. NameError: name 'instance_dict' is not defined.

```
def Objfun(instance_dict, solution, show = False):
dict = instance_dict
t = 0   #starting time
objfun_value = 0
for job in solution:
    C_i = t + dict[job]["processing_time"]  
    d_i = dict[job]["due_date"]   
    T_i = max(0, C_i - d_i)    
    W_i = dict[job]["weight"] 

    objfun_value +=  W_i * T_i
    t = C_i
if show == True:
    print("The Objective function value for {} solution schedule is: {}".format(solution ,objfun_value))
return objfun_value

solution_1 = [1,2,5,6,8,9,10,3,4,7]
solution_2 = [2,3,5,10,6,8,9,4,7,1]

Objfun(instance_dict, solution_1, show=True)
Objfun(instance_dict, solution_2, show=True)
```

Comment: do you ever assign `instance_dict`? you don't seem to have any line like `instance_dict = ...`

Comment: Sidenote: It's generally a bad idea to shadow builtins like `dict` with local variables. Consider picking a more descriptive variable name.

Comment: ‘dict = instance_dict‘ should be ‘instance_dict = dict()’

Answer (score 0):

The last two lines of your code `Objfun(instance_dict, solution_1, show=True)` are referencing a variable, `instance_dict`, that is not defined anywhere. Thus the error, as you are trying to use an undefined variable.